# Disable hub horizontal scrolling when showing menu flyout in windows and win phone 8.1

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a hub item with many hub sections inside. I create a user control to present an item in hub sections.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Holding="Grid_Holding">    
    <Grid x:Name="flyoutContainer" Background="Transparent" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource MenuFlyout}"/>
</Grid>
```

When I'm holding the item, it will show a menu fly out. The problem here is when i'm holding the item in the main page, the hub container still can be scrolled when i move my pointer. How can I disable the scrolling of the hub container?..

I have tried to turn of the scroll viewer of hub container by the below code but it's only fire when i released my pointer:

```
private void EnableHubScrollViewer()
    {
        var viewer = FindChild<ScrollViewer>(ParentHub, "ScrollViewer");              
        viewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;

        this.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

Please help me to solve this problem..Thanks